# NULL rejection in mysql

Tags: mysql

Today i was reading MySQL Docs on outer joins ,there I found that certain conditions are null rejected when an outer join is done

```
T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.A=T2.A
```

Conditions such as these are null-rejected:(not able to understand from docs [original docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/outer-join-simplification.html))

```
T2.B IS NOT NULL,
T2.B > 3,
T2.C <= T1.C,
T2.B < 2 OR T2.C > 1
```

Can anyone explain in simple words .

1. Why are these conditions rejected
2. What is the affect on output produced by the query if some conditions are rejected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This discussion of "null-rejected" conditions is simply about optimizing queries that are more complex than they need to be; it doesn't change the behavior of a query at all.

Consider this query:

```
select * from table1
    left outer join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
    where table2.id is not null
```

This query is written as an outer join, and yet it also discards any row in which table2 is null (the *null-rejected condition* is the condition in the `where` clause that excludes any rows that are null).

The `where` clause in this query rejects any of the "outer rows" from the outer join.  This  means that it is not really an outer join at all; it could be rewritten as this:

```
select * from table1
    inner join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
```

**MySQL recognizes this situation and automatically optimizes to the simplified query**, rather than doing all the extra work of performing an outer join and discarding the rows.

Comment: Thanks dan this one was simple.

Comment: The name 'null-rejected' is confusing, should be 'null-rejecting' by all means. It would instantly make sense in 'a null-rejecting condition'.